# I2c Master testing on FPGA board

Tags: fpga, xilinx, i2c, xilinx-ise, xilinx-edk

I have implemented i2c master code for reading temperature value from temp sensor(slave).i am testing my code on FPGA evolution board.FPGA is Microsemi nano very basic FPGA.How can I test my master without connecting to the slave device?

Comment: You can try creating a slave i2c simulator that behaves like the slave device.  Simulations will help a lot to get things working prior to porting code to hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend writing a test bench that simulates the behavior of a slave device and checks for the correct sequence of actions from your I2C master and use it in simulation.